# Bower Install Uses git protocol even after changing the configuration

Tags: git, github, bower, bower-install

I am trying to install components using Bower and I behind my company's proxy. Initially I got the following error,

```
PS C:\App> bower instal
l jquery
bower not-cached    git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
bower resolve       git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
bower cached        https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angul
ar.min.js
bower validate      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angul
ar.min.js#*
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github
.com/jquery/jquery.git", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
```

After searching around and found an alternate to use https: protocol instead of git using the following command,

```
git config --global url.https://.insteadOf git://
```

after I listed the configs,

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
url.https://.insteadof=git://
```

Even after doing all these steps, I am still getting the above mentioned error again.

Any idea what am I missing?

Raaj

Comment: I searched up in windows and found the actual file location and updated it. Now it works. Still wondering where did the command line edit went

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and the problem was that I was using Cygwin. `git config --global` was adding the configuration to my Cygwin home (`~/.gitconfig`), but when bower was executing git, it was using the configuration on my Windows home (`C:\Users\name\.gitconfig`).

Copying `~/.gitconfig` to `C:\Users\name\.gitconfig` fixed the problem.